# Adobe CC motion presents in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, adobe-animate

I've created a simple animation which uses the motion present "fly-in-blur-right". Here's how it moves within the stage:

[image: Adobe CC motion blur]

When I output to HTML5 Canvas, it converts the animation to a classic tween, moving from one point to another. I receive the following output warning from Adobe CC when I hit publish:

```
WARNINGS:
** 1 Bitmaps packed successfully into 1 spritesheet(s).
Frame numbers in EaselJS start at 0 instead of 1. For example, this affects gotoAndStop and gotoAndPlay calls. (4)
Feature not supported: Bevel, gradient glow, and gradient bevel filters.
Motion tweens are published as frame by frame animations. Use classic tweens where possible. (2)
```

From this, I understand that a number of filters aren't supported. Is there a way to get the desired effect within HTML5 Canvas? Is there a JS library I can utilise?